# UITableView push different view controller for each selected row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a UITableView with 10 rows. Each cell needs to go to a separate View Controller. I have embedded the UITableView in a Navigation Controller and created the DetailViewController. I am unsure on how to send each cell to a different View Controller.

Comment: `UIScrollView` does not have rows. Are you sure it is not a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a UITableView instead of a UIScrollView you would just have to implement the following delegate call in the class containing the UITableView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Use indexPath to determine which of the 10 rows was actually selected
switch(indexPath.row){
case 0:
//Create and fire off a DetailViewController for row 0
break;
case 1:
//Create and fire off a DetailViewController for row 1
break;
}
}
```

As well here is a tutorial explaining row selection in UITableView:[UITableView Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/)
Also official Apple Doc:[Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Sorry I fixed that up now, It was a UITableView. Thanks for the quick answer I'll try it out now

Comment: It gives an error saying that it expects an int not an index path. What can I do about this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it worked. But the switch statement seems to have a problem with UIStoryboard. Do I need to create them somewhere else and call them in there?